# recursive contract like Typed Racket's 'Rec' type

Tags: racket, contract

Typed Racket's `Rec` type is an easy way to make recursive types:

```
#lang typed/racket/base

(define (deep (n : Integer)) : (Rec T (U Integer (List T)))
  (if (zero? n)
    n
    (list (deep (- n 1)))))
```

Is there a similar way to make a recursive contract?
Racket's [`recursive-contract`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/contract-utilities.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._recursive-contract%29%29) is not the same.

Comment: Original Q/A on Slack: https://racket.slack.com/archives/C06V96CKX/p1496706050248551

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contract expressions are just expressions! You can write a macro that takes input like Typed Racket's `Rec` and replaces the "recursive identifier" with a self-reference.

Here's an example `rec/c` combinator, where `(rec/c id ctc)` expands to `ctc` with all occurrences of `id` replaced with `(recursive-contract id)`.

```
#lang racket/base
(require racket/contract (for-syntax racket/base syntax/parse))

(define-syntax-rule (rec/c t ctc)
  (letrec ([rec-ctc
            (let-syntax ([t (syntax-parser (_:id #'(recursive-contract rec-ctc)))])
              ctc)])
      rec-ctc))

(define/contract (deep n)
  (-> integer? (rec/c t (or/c integer? (list/c t))))
  (if (zero? n)
    n
    (list (deep (- n 1)))))

(deep 4)
```

Note: the pattern `_:id` matches any use of `t` as an identifier.